# Yii2. Пустое поле загрузки файла при редактировании

Tags: php, yii2, yii

Ситуация такова. Имеется поле file, которое загружает файл и сохраняет имя файла в БД. Если я редактирую запись, в которой уже имеется загруженный ранее файл, но при этом оставляю поле file нетронутым (например, требуется изменить только заголовок), то соответствующее поле в БД становится пустым. Кроме того, если поле является обязательным для заполнения, то форма вообще отказывает отправляться, требуя загрузить новый файл. Как правильно поступать в такой ситуации?

**Update**: добавлю код своего actionUpdate, что бы было нагляднее (по совету @YaroslavMolchan).

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            $directory = Service::getFileDirectory();
            $mainImage = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'main_image');

            if ($mainImage) {
                $uid = uniqid(time(), true);
                $model->main_image = $uid . '.' . $mainImage->extension;
                $mainImage->saveAs($directory . $model->main_image);
            }

            if ($model->save())
                return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } 
        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Я вижу 2 варианта.

Первый вариант: в месте где вы сохраняете данные просто проверяйте заполенено ли поле, если да - значит загружаете его и обновляете название файла в бд:

```
if ($form->validate()) {
    if ($form->fileName) {
        //Грузим файл и пишем в модель
    }
}
```

Второй вариант: к примеру поле в таблице у вас `fileName` вы на форме создаете поле `file` и так же если поле заполнено сохраняете его и передаете значение в `$model->fileName` и тем самым если поле будет пустое вы не запишете его в базу, потому что разные имена, к примеру:

```
if ($form->validate()) {
    if ($form->file) {
        //Грузим файл и пишем в модель
        $path = '/path/to/file.jpg';
        $form->file->saveAs($path);
        $user->fileName = $path;
    }
}
```

Думаю суть вы поняли, а вообще лучше показывать ещё код.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я могу придумать способы обойти эту проблему. Просто, я надеялся, что фреймворк предусматривает подобные случаи, а я просто не знаю такие механизмы. Я пробовал использовать свойство skipOnEmpty, но это не помогло. Я делал так:
`[['main_image'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => true, 'extensions' => 'png, jpg, jpeg'],`

Кстати, я добавил код в текст своего основного вопроса, для наглядности

Comment: @Skiv проще создать чисто модель для валидации и тогда не будет проблем с пустым полем и потом данные переносить уже в ActiveRecord модель, возможно тогда и `skipOnEmpty` отработает